# Add another Stroyboard from another project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

Hi everyone I have to add an storyboard from another iOS project. Firstly I tried to copy storyboard file and .swift files related about viewcontrollers into my project directory. Then in Xcode I added them with add files to "project name". Copy if needed and create folder reference are checked. But the problem is when I run project and show that new Storyboards view I got an error message for all outlets.

Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7fd51cf04e70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bitkiAdiView."

When I delete reference from Connection inspector and from vc.swift file and again set with same name also I got this error. But if I do outlet name different then it solves. In this storyboard is a lot of outlets cause that I don't want to change names. What should I do ?

Comment: The custom class for that scene either isn't set or isn't being found so a `UIViewController` is being instantiated instead. This doesn't have the outlets.  Check and reset the custom view controller class for the scene(s). It probably has the wrong module name since you have moved it from another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do copying process step by step. Firstly install pods then move swift files. Be sure if there is no error

- Check pods install again
- Check maybe there is a conflict    where
  you changed the code
- You can try to use pods that you    install
  new in some page